# applicationContext.xml with datasource or hibernate.cfg.xml. Difference?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2

Want to clear some confusion. I have applicationContext.xml.

**Question 1:** Whats the difference between 1 & 2. Are they both same with different approach?

**Question 2:**

I asked question on Spring forum regarding some problem. Onething he mentioned about pooling is below

> if you need/want to use the internal connection pooling for hibernate
>   I would advice against it and simply configure a datasource which
>   supports connection pooling and inject that into your
>   sessionfactorybean.

*internal connection pooling for hibernate =* This is **number 2 below**. Right?

*simply configure a datasource which supports connection pooling and inject that into your sessionfactorybean =* This is **number 1 below**. right?

**1# -**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="16000"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
    </bean>

 <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**2# -**

Pooling and connection info is in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Hi, i too am confused on which approach to use. i think i will go for the cfg.xml as this seperates and decouples the hibernate config away from this applicationContext making it easier to create multiple data config sources.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

Both approaches are the same. By default , hibernate reads the configuration from `classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml` to build `SessionFactory` . `LocalSessionFactoryBean` just allows you to setup hibernate configuration inside `applicationContext.xml` instead of `hibernate.cfg.xml` .

If a same property is specified in both files , depending on the property , it will has addictive effect or the properties specified in  `applicationContext.xml` will take higher priority such that those values in  `hibernate.cfg.xml` will be ignored.

For method 1, `annotatedClasses` and `hibernateProperties` should have the addictive effect with the corresponding values in `hibernate.cfg.xml` . The  DBCP dataSouruce in `applicationContext.xml` should cause the related properties in `hibernate.cfg.xml` being ignored.

**Answer 2:**

For method 2 , if you don't specify any properties of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` , all the hibernate configurations are specified by the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. If there are no connection pool configured in `hibernate.cfg.xml` , [hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is used by default](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) , which is quite rudimentary and not intended for use in a production system, or even for performance testing.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is to build a session factory, you will get the same result with both approaches. I don't think one can do more than the other.

In my opinion, you would use the *hibernate.cfg.xml* approach when you are not using Spring. When JUnit testing your DAOs for example. Not having to build a Spring application context makes your tests run faster.

However, when you are using Spring, I think it's a good thing to keep your datasource separated from the session factory. You are using Spring for dependency inject, right? Why not using spring to give your session factory what it needs?

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "Why not using spring to give your session factory what it needs?"

Comment: I mean, inject the datasource into your session factory, as you would inject a dao into a service, or a service into a controller. It gives you the same benefits: you integrate components at one place: the application context. You need to switch to alternative datasource implementation, you know where to look. You could even choose which datasource implementation to inject using property placeholders.