# What strategy is actually selected for "GenerationType.AUTO" for the major databases?

Tags: database, hibernate

The [Hibernate documentations (5.1.2.2. Identifier generator)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id) states

> AUTO: selects IDENTITY, SEQUENCE or TABLE depending upon the capabilities of the underlying database.

But I'm unable to find a documentation/overview what @GeneratedValue strategy is used for the specific databases when defining them as GenerationType.AUTO.

Does anybody know whether someone maintains a list of the actual generation strategy for the major databases (e.g. Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL, ...)? And where to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link is about Java Persistence API and seems regularly updated.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing

> ## Identity sequencing
>
> Identity sequencing uses special IDENTITY columns in the database to
>   allow the database to automatically assign an id to the object when
>   its row is inserted. Identity columns are supported in many databases,
>   such as **MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, and PostgreSQL**. Oracle does
>   not support IDENTITY columns but its is possible to simulate them
>   using sequence objects and triggers.
>
> ## Sequence objects
>
> Sequence objects use special database objects to generate ids.
>   Sequence objects are only supported in some databases, such as **Oracle,
>   DB2, and Postgres**. Usually, a SEQUENCE object has a name, an
>   INCREMENT, and other database object settings. Each time the
>   .NEXTVAL is selected the sequence is incremented by the
>   INCREMENT.

**Edit**

If the database such as DB2 supports both IDENTITY columns and Sequences hibernate chooses Identity columns, see [Dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.java):

```
public Class getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass() {
    if ( supportsIdentityColumns() ) {
        return IdentityGenerator.class;
    }
    else if ( supportsSequences() ) {
        return SequenceGenerator.class;
    }
    else {
        return TableHiLoGenerator.class;
    }
}
```

You can check what is returned from supportsIdentityColumns() and supportsSequences() for each database by looking at the relevant dialect in the [`org.hibernate.dialect`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect) package.

Comment: That's interesting information. But it doesn't answer the question e.g. whether Hibernate selects sequence or identity as an strategy for DB2.

Comment: I edited my answer with details of how to work this out from the sourcecode.

Comment: If you don't specify `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` Hibernate uses the native mechanism and I can see how it works. +1 for that. But if you use the recommended setting (with mentioned property set to true), Hibernate will choose some `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator` and I have a hard time tracking in the sources where this leads for each of the databases by default.