# How to change Hibernate GenerationType identifier depending on the underlying database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a project called **main_project** (uses spring-boot v2) that contains all configuration classes including **JPA configuration**. The **main_project** also has entity classes (Like User, Personnel).

The JPA configuration for **managed entity class** in **main_project** is like below:

```
@Entity
public abstract class MainEntity<T extends Serializable> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(GenerationType=?)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private T id;
}

@Entity
public class Personnel extends MainEntity<Long> {
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    // other proprties
}
```

Other projects are using **main_project** as dependency for bootstrapping. Other projects that depends on **main_project** can use Personnel or User and ... entities and they can have different DBMS's like **MySQL** or **Oracle**.

When i used **main_project** as a dependency in project **A** , entity class of **A** project `extends MainEntity<?>` and creates it's own entity classes and have its own database configuration file.

my problem is on type of DBMS and **GenerationType** on **id** property in **main_project**.

- 1) when **A** project uses **Mysql** database, **MainEntity** must have:

  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
- 2) when **A** project uses **Oracle** database, **MainEntity** must have:

  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")`
  `@SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "id_seq", allocationSize=1)`

How project A can detect its database type and switch between above approaches?

*I think that i need reflected java util that in runtime and add some annotations based on databases type! is it right?*

I also have read, [this_post_19875993](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875993/what-strategy-is-actually-selected-for-generationtype-auto-for-the-major-datab) but it didn't helped.

[this_post_30731627](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731627/hibernate-auto-key-generation-with-mysql-and-oracle) explained that we can select one of custom **GenerationType** but i want to select automatically without any changes to **main_project**, because **A** project can not change **MainEntity** class of **main_project** and just can used it.

Comment: @vlad-mihalcea what is your idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`SEQUENCE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-replace-the-table-identifier-generator-with-either-sequence-or-identity-in-a-portable-way/) identifier in your base class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "id_seq", allocationSize=1)
private Long id;
```

And override it for MySQL using the external `mysql-orm.xml` configuration file:

```
<entity-mappings
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1"
        >
    <package>com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.identifier.global</package>
    <entity class="Post" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

So, while for Oracle and PostgreSQL, you won't have to provide the `mysql-orm.xml`, for MySQL, just supply this file via the `persistence.xml` onfiguration file when you build the project using the mysql profile:

```
<persistence
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
 
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
 
        <provider>
            org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
        </provider>
 
        <mapping-file>
            mappings/identifier/global/mysql-orm.xml
        </mapping-file>
 
        <class>
            com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.identifier.global.Post
        </class>
 
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `orm.xml` in project A  to override the mapping configuration for the ID column according to the [JPA specification](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa-xml-files):

> An object/relational mapping XML file named orm.xml may be specified
>   in the META-INF directory in the root of the persistence unit or in
>   the META-INF directory of any jar file referenced by the
>   persistence.xml.
>
> Alternatively, or in addition, one or more mapping files may be
>   referenced by the mapping-file elements of the persistence-unit
>   element. These mapping files may be present anywhere on the class
>   path.
>
> — Section 8.2.1.6.2 of the JPA 2.1 Specification

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750777/orm-xml-does-not-override-annotations?rq=1) and [this](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-override-primary-key-generation-strategy/) for an example.

Comment: hi. thanks for reply, but with this approach i must create orm.xml per application, and then added whole of entities of main_project and child_project in it. is there any programmatically approach to automatically override mapping configuration for the id?

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically , I believe you need to try to play with Hibernate Metadata API  (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native-metadata) . Alternatively , I would write an programme to scan all the entity classes and then generate orm.xml  , which should be a much easier task IMO.

Comment: ok thanks, i try to write an program to generate orm.xml. just, Is it possible to add to the hibernate framework later?